# How to get exchange by coins with two denominations?

Tags: logic

Develop a method `change(amount)` that for any integer amount in the range from 24 to 1000 returns a list consisting of numbers 5 and 7 only, such that their sum is equal to amount. For example, `change(28)` may return `[7, 7, 7, 7]`, while `change(49)` may return `[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]` or `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7]` or `[7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7]`.

I have written something like this. But it isn't working right.

```
enter code here

def change (amount):
assert (amount >=24)
if amount == 24:
    return [5, 5, 7, 7]
if amount == 29:
    return [5, 5, 5, 7, 7]
if amount == 40:
    return [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]


coins = change(amount - 5)
coins.append(5)
return coins
```

for coins in range(24, 1000):
    print(coins)

Comment: Please spend less time apologising and provide a [mre] - what does *"isn't working right"* actually mean? Is that your code, or just *"something like"* it? Take the [tour], review [ask], and [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, you should find two numbers:

- the number of coins with value 7 (let it be **countA**) and
- the number of coins with value 5 (let it be **countB**)

As you can see `0 <= countA <= sum/7`. Then `sum - countA * 7` should be divided by 5 **without remainder**.

So, the simple implementation in java can be like this:

```java
import java.util.Collections;
// ... 
public List<Integer> getExchange(int sum)
{
   int coinA = 7;
   int coinB = 5;

   int maxCountOfCoinA = sum / coinA;
   int countA = 0;
   int countB = 0;
   for (int count = 0; count <= maxCountOfCoinA; count++)
   {
      int remains = sum - count * coinA;
      if (remains % coinB == 0)
      {
         countA = count;
         countB = remains / coinB;
         break;
      }
   }

   List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
   result.addAll(Collections.nCopies(countA, coinA));
   result.addAll(Collections.nCopies(countB, coinB));
   return result;
}
```